# Where are devise parameters documented

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

As a newbie to devise and angularjs, perhaps looking at wrong places, I can't seem to find where the parameters are documented for the following routes:

```
$ rake routes
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          user/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          user/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         user/sessions#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#show
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)         user/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     user/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    user/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)         user/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)         user/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)           user/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                  user/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          user/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)             user/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                  user/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                  user/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                  user/registrations#destroy
```

Running a piece of sample code, I can see the following in the log:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-15 16:49:35 -0800
Processing by User::SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"guest@local.host", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "session"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"guest@local.host", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
```

Because I don't have sample code for every route, how can I figure out the right parameter for the above routes? Thanks.

Comment: AngularJS and Devise – authentication with a rails server (https://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/angularjs-and-devise-authentication-with-a-rails-server/) spells out a lot of relevant details. Also, A small AngularJS Service to interact with Devise Authentication (https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise) can be useful.